# Navigation Bar Large Title - Animation Issue

Tags: html, ios, swift, xcode, uinavigationbar

I'm using the large title on the navigation bar, and when I tap on a cell to go on the next controller, the large title has a strange animation (as you can see on the gif below). It's doesn't disappear immediately.

I tried the following solution but nothing (https://www.morningswiftui.com/blog/fix-large-title-animation-on-ios13)

[image]

**My Code:**

On the first View Controller:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        navigationItem.title = "New Order"
        navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
}
```

On the Second View Controller (With the large title):

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        navigationItem.title = "Menu"
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = false
}
```

**Edit:**

Fabio's answer is the solution but now I have another problem:

When I tap on a cell a part of the navigation bar is black (as you can see below)

[image]

Comment: Could you show me the code?

Comment: have you tried add the function `viewWillDisappear` and remove the navigation title?

Comment: I add my code! I have tried the function viewWillDisappear but without results.

Comment: @AlexGiatrakis can you please explain a little bit in detail that how did you solve the issue with navigation title. I am also facing the same issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

for second issue:
in SceneDelegate: `var window: UIWindow?`
in the function scene put this line:

```
window?.backgroundColor = .yourColor
```

like this:

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
    // Use this method to optionally configure and attach the UIWindow `window` to the provided UIWindowScene `scene`.
    // If using a storyboard, the `window` property will automatically be initialized and attached to the scene.
    // This delegate does not imply the connecting scene or session are new (see `application:configurationForConnectingSceneSession` instead).
    guard let _ = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
    window?.backgroundColor = .white
}
```

set the color you want and that's it :)

Comment: Thanks! It works! Can you explain to me exactly what this line of code does?

Comment: simply the app background.... the black bar that you see is the background of the app, it isn't a bar :)

Comment: or set extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars to true, cause viewcontroller's frame is not fullscreen

Answer (score 7):

Try to insert On the first View Controller:

```
 override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    navigationItem.title = "New Order"
    navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
    navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode =  .always
 }
```

and On the Second View Controller:

```
 override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    navigationItem.title = "Menu"
    navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .never
}
```

Comment: Yep this work if you don't set prefersLargeTitles to false in second VC.

Answer (score 3):

Try using `viewDidLoad` instead of `viewWillAppear` in Second View Controller

Comment: This was exactly the problem with my implementation.

Comment: From storyboard I had to set `largeTitleDisplayMode` to `.never` in detail view controller and had to remove `prefersLargeTitle` from there in viewWillAppear.

Answer (score 2):

copy this extension to setting navigation bar:

```
extension UIViewController {
func configureNavigationBar(largeTitleColor: UIColor, backgoundColor: UIColor, tintColor: UIColor, title: String, preferredLargeTitle: Bool) {
if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
    let navBarAppearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
    navBarAppearance.configureWithOpaqueBackground()
    navBarAppearance.largeTitleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: largeTitleColor]
    navBarAppearance.titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: largeTitleColor]
    navBarAppearance.backgroundColor = backgoundColor
    navigationController?.navigationBar.standardAppearance = navBarAppearance
    navigationController?.navigationBar.compactAppearance = navBarAppearance
    navigationController?.navigationBar.scrollEdgeAppearance = navBarAppearance

    navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = preferredLargeTitle
    navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
    navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = tintColor
    navigationItem.title = title

} else {
    // Fallback on earlier versions
    navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = backgoundColor
    navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = tintColor
    navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
    navigationItem.title = title
}}}
```

How to use, call on viewWillAppear

```
configureNavigationBar(largeTitleColor: .yourColor, backgoundColor: .yourColor, tintColor: .yourColor, title: "YourTitle", preferredLargeTitle: true)
```

now in didSelectRow call second controller with pushVievController like this:

```
let controller = YourViewController()
    navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)
```

in viewDidLoad of second controller set large title to false like this:

```
navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .never
```

Set ViewController-based status bar to NO in info.plist if you want light Content. 
If you don't want largeTitles set it to false
Tested on iOS 13, hope this help :)
Now you're ok :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried everything you told me but the issue still exists.

Comment: @AlexGiatrakis summary: copy the extension in first controller, configure navBar in viewWillAppear of first Controller: configureNavigationBar(largeTitleColor: .yourColor, backgoundColor: .yourColor, tintColor: .yourColor, title: "YourTitle", preferredLargeTitle: true), now call action pushViewController to present second controller, copy this line in viewDidLoad of second controller: navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .never and you're done.... tested

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But now I have another issue. I have edited my post.

Comment: without using UINavigationBarAppearance, there are display bugs in the background of the nav bar when you're using large titles. thanks @Fabio

Comment: @spnkr Glad to have been helpful :)

Answer (score 1):

So you want, your first view controller has large title, then add this following code into your first view controller in `viewWillAppear(animated:)`

```
self.navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .automatic
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
```

And you want, your next view controller has not large title, then add this following code into your next view controller in `viewWillAppear(animated:)`

```
self.navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .never
```

The conclusion is you just need set `self.navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles` to `true` just if you want your view controller need show large title at beginning of appearing view